# iOS How can I use pushviewcontroller with NavigationController(Objective - c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change view by clicking button with NavigationController

So I added a button to Main.storyboard and write some codes like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

in my ViewController.m  (Created automatically when I made my project)

And I added method

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

}

(I made SecondViewController.m, SecondViewController.h, SecondViewController.xib)

After this, I started the application and clicked the button but the screen didn't change.

Actually, when I added log like

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);
```

null was printed.

I think I need to add some code about NavigationController to AppDelegate.m but I don't know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: Did you embed "Navigation Controller" in your storyboard? If you don't have storyboard, how are you showing FirstViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

in Appdelegate.m

```
`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"
                                                   bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}`
```

You need to embed Navigation Controller through code or Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

First select your initial viewcontroller in storyboard and embed it in NavigationController.
[image]

Then give a storyboard identifier to the second viewcontroller.

Then lastly instantiate Second ViewController from storyboard and push it.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:entryController animated:YES];
}
```